# Using JobQueue for different users

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I want to have a notebook Telegram Bot that works like a reminder. The bot basically will help users to take notes and remind them after a certain time (I know there are millions of bots like this one, but it is just for educational purposes). I used [JobQueue](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.jobqueue.html), but I think it just works well for single user. For example: 
User A ---> Write me in 5 min 
User B ---> Write me in 15 min 
The bot writes user B in 5 min since it is the last user who access to the JobQueue. How can I solve the problem and have different JobQueues for different users?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please have a look at the [JobQueue tutorial](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions-–-JobQueue) and the [`timerbot.py`](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/tree/master/examples#timerbotpy) example - they showcase exactly this.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!